# how to link to a specific point on a page with cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to get a link in cakephp to point to a specific place on another page but what I imagined would work doesn't.

I'm using

```
<a name="Telstra"></a>
<a href="/mysite/sponsors/index#Telstra">Telstra</a>
```

Can anyone tell me the correct way?

Comment: As you can see from the answers, no one really knows what exactly your problem is. "_doesn't work_" is never an appropriate problem description. You don't know how that add anchors to helper genereated links? Once clicked it won't jump to the section defined in the anchor? etc... ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the built-in **link** function of CakePHP. try to use this code.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('NameOfLink', array('controller' => 'ControllerName', 'action' => 'FunctionName/#Telstra')); ?>
```

Comment: +1 , correct answer :) I dont understand `#WHY` people cant Press `+1` Button if answer is correct ? Is it that much difficult?

Comment: very well said. +1 for you @jQueryAngryBird (y)

Comment: -1 Even though it might work, this is actually _not_ the correct way of doing it (@jQueryAngryBird), the hash part of a URL should be defined via the `#` key in the URL array as shown in Abhisheks answer. Adding it to the `action` will break routing and everything else that involves matching the action name.

Answer (score 4):

See this url from cakephp docs:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::url

For creating link only

```
echo $this->Html->url(array(
    "controller" => "posts",
    "action" => "search",
    "#" => "first"
));
```

and in your case for creating the link with anchor tag,

```
echo $this->Html->link('Telestra',array(
    "controller" => "sponsors",
    "action" => "index",
    "#" => "Telstra"
));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load on a specific part of the page you must use ID on the element of your target rather than Name.

Example:

```
//Your target element on a page
<a name="Telstra"></a>

//URL that will redirect you to your target element.
<a href="/mysite/sponsors/index#Telstra">Telstra</a>
```

Or might as well code it the cakePhp style. :)

```
//URL
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Telstra', array('controller' => 'YourController', 'action' => 'YourFUnction', '#TargetElement'));

//Target Element
<a name="Telstra"></a>
```

Good Luck!

Comment: +1 , correct answer :) I dont understand `#WHY` people cant Press `+1` Button if answer is correct ? Is it that much difficult?

Answer (score 0):

you need put a route in the folde of configuration /app/config/routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/index', array('controller' => 'yourController', 'action' => 'index'));
```

or

```
Router::connect('/index/*', array('controller' => 'yourController', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the parameter you're meaning to put  is 'id' and not 'name' and I think you can just put #idName instead of the whole link.

For example:

```
<a id="Telstra"></a>
<a href="#Telstra">Telstra</a>
```

For more information you can check here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: hello ,Didnt he asked `"*USING CAKEPHP*"`

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird My apologise, I kinda jumped the gun a little based on the example given.